# Best macOS software for very large vectors

Tags: pdf, mac

I want to build very large and detailed vectors to be used as map-like interfaces (via PDF viewers).

macOS Preview *for viewing* allows you to zoom to 30x (3000%).

I tried web based Figma, but this crashes my browser tab.

Sketch seems to work.

Are there any other macOS vector editor programs that would perform well with a lot of items on the canvas?

Comment: ermmm.. Inscape, Adobe Illustrator... "Preview" is *not*  a vector application.

Comment: Preview is a vector viewer (PDF's contain vectors). Have updated my question.

Comment: Yes its a PDF viewer (one of the worst), in that respect Preview is no different than a web browser to view a PDF. Preview is dumb as to what's vector and what isn't. It merely reads the PDF.

Comment: My experience is different. Preview uses the least CPU/RAM and has highest FPS of most of the vector viewers I have tried.

Comment: Preview fails in many areas - overprints, spot colors, etc. And it's not a "vector viewer", it's a PDF viewer. It's the PDF that is creating *raster* previews based upon the PDFs internal vector data. If Preview works for you that's great. Continue using it. But it's the PDF which is doing the work. Preview is merely faster for you because it's a *local app* and not an online viewer. Yes Preview is far better than web browser PDF plug ins.. but it also pales in comparison to Acrobat or Reader - actual PDF tools.

Comment: The PDF is just a binary file - it does not do any work. Preview reads the binary data and renders it to screen. Vectors are stored in the PDF, and are rendered by Preview for viewing. Hence, in this case, Preview is a "vector viewer". But thanks for the other information - interesting.

Comment: @zino pdf isn't actually binary is mostly ascii text but can have compressed blocks. You can easily edit pdf files in text editors. But yes we have a lot of questions that turn out to be of the form "preview is broken". Its easy to be fast if you ignore part of the file.